# Microsoft Graph API Authentication_MissingOrMalformed

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using **oauth2/token** to authenticate my application and get the access_token. Bellow is the java code which is working fine.

```
    private String getToken() throws Exception {
        String access_token = "";
        String url = "https://login.windows.net/MyApplication_ID_here/oauth2/token";
        HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "MyApplication_ID_here"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "MyApplication_secret_here"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println("Sending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        String responseAsString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println(responseAsString);
        try {
            access_token = responseAsString.split(",")[6].split("\"")[3]; // get the access_token from response 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return access_token;
}
```

**Response :**

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":"3599","ext_expires_in":"0","expires_on":"1493011626","not_before":"1493007726","resource":"https://graph.microsoft.com","access_token":"eyJ0e..."}
```

then I am using access_token to load the **memberOf** value which is not working and gives me the **Access Token missing or malformed** error. Bellow is the java code

```
private void getMemberOf()
{
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try
    {
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://graph.windows.net/MyApplication_ID_here/users/test@testABC.onmicrosoft.com/memberOf?api-version=1.6");
        URI uri = builder.build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

**Response :**

```
Response Code : 401
{"odata.error":{"code":"Authentication_MissingOrMalformed","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Access Token missing or malformed."},"date":"2017-04-24T04:39:38","requestId":"c5aa2abe-9b37-4611-8db1-107e3ec08c14","values":null}}
```

**Can someone please tell me which part of the above request is wrong? Am I not setting access_token correctly?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to your code , your access token is for resource "https://graph.microsoft.com"(Microsoft Graph API) ,But the access token is used for "https://graph.windows.net"(AAD Graph API) :

```
 URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://graph.windows.net/MyApplication_ID_here/users/test@testABC.onmicrosoft.com/memberOf?api-version=1.6");
```

If you want to call Azure AD graph api , you need to get access token for Azure AD Graph API .

Comment: Thanks!!!! after changing  urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com")); to urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("resource", "https://graph.windows.net")); everything works fine now

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue while performing the CRUD operation on Azure AD B2C service via AD Graph API for user management.

The idea is to get the access token for the resource "graph.windows.net" instead I was using my tenant App Id URI as it was suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/dn645543%28v%3Dazure.100%29).

*might help people who faced the same issue and landed up here